# Dual problem for linear programming

Tags: linear-programming

I tried to solve this problem, but I am not sure if I am right.
Otherwise, I find some solution in one book and solution is very questionable. One more thing, I am not sure how to this problems when there are equality constraints.
Find dual problem for min $-x_1+2x_2+3x_3$ subject to
$x_1-x_2+2x_3=1$,
$2x_1+x_2<=3$,
$x_1<=0$, $x_2>=0$, $x_3>=0$
and solve it.

First, I use change $_1=−_1$
where $_1 \ge 0$
. I observe these three constraints: $−_1−_2+2_3\ge 1$
, $_1+_2−2_3\ge −1$, $−2_1+_2\ge −3$ and create dual problem: $\max _1−_2−3_3$ subject to $−_1+_2−2_3\le −1$ , $−_1+_2+1_3\le 2$, $2_1−2_2\le 3$
. Is this right?

Comment: include what you tried

Comment: First, I use change $x_1=-a_1$ where $a_1 \geq 0$. I observe these three constraints: $ -a_1 - a_2+2a_3 \geq 1$, $ a_1 + a_2-2a_3 \geq -1$, $-2a-1+a-2 \geq -3$ and create dual problem: max $y_1-y_2-3y_3$ subject to $-y_1+y_2-2y-3 \leq -1$ , $-y_1+y_2+1y-3 \leq 2$, $2y_1-2y_2  \leq 3$. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not right. You primal problem is

\begin{align}
& \texttt{Min} \ -x_1+2x_2+3x_3 \\ & \  \ x_1-x_2+2x_3=1 \qquad (\color{red}{y_1})\\ & 2x_1+x_2\leq 3   \qquad (\color{red}{y_2}) \\ & x_1\leq 0, x_2,x_3\geq 0
\end{align}

So $y_1$ and $y_2$ are your dual variables. We can use the table below to formulate the dual problem. We have to read it from the right to the left, since the primal problem is a min-problem:

\begin{align}
& \texttt{Max} \ y_1+3y_2 \\ & \  \ y_1+2y_2\geq -1 \qquad (\color{blue}{x_1})\\ & -y_1+y_2\leq 2   \qquad (\color{blue}{x_2}) \\ & 2y_1\leq 3   \qquad (\color{blue}{x_3}) \\ & y_1 \textrm{free}, y_2 \leq 0
\end{align}

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Now this maximum problem we solve finding KKT points, don't we? One more thing, why is A transpose on both sides?

Comment: I wouldn't call them kkt points. We just Look for the extreme point(s). Don't care much about the notation. In this case it has something to do wird the indexes, I guess. It always  depends on the definition.

Comment: Allright. One more question, is same procedure when we solve maximum and when we solve minimum function finding KKT points?

Comment: @Broj1 If you have to minimize $z$, then it is equivalent to maximize $-z$. z is the objective function here. // In this case the dual (max-problem) is probably more comfortable, since it has two variables only. That means one can try to solve it graphically.

Comment: Thank you. Bye.

Comment: @Broj1 You´re welcome. Mark the answer as accepted. Thanks in advance. Bye.